# How do I run a Java 1.0/1.1 Applet on a modern system?

Tags: java, applet

I have an old Java Applet that needs to run in JDK 1.0 or 1.1. How do I run it on a modern system, for example Windows or Linux on a 64bit CPU?

Comment: In a Virtual Machine that has an old operating system for a guest machine.

Comment: JDK is backwards compatible are you sure it doesn’t simply work with say x86 Java 8? At least Java 8 is still supported and security issues are fixed

Comment: JDK is the development kit (and tools.. etc), JRE is the runtime environment.  It sounds like you are only trying to run the thing.  That isn't the JDK and as @Ramhound points out.. it should simply work (but doesn't always).

Comment: You can try Appletviewer which is included in JDK (not sure about JRE) up to Java 9 or 10 ( so Java 8 would be a good choice).

Comment: It uses the `sun.audio` API which was deprecated in Java 2. I have tried newer JRE:s but it did't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using our [CheerpJ Applet Runner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) extension for Chrome (free for non-commercial use). It is based on CheerpJ, a technology that allows to run unmodified Java applets and applications in the browser in HTML5/JavaScript/WebAssembly.

If you can modify the page you can even integrate CheerpJ so that the applet will start automatically for any user. For more information see the "Converting an applet" section here: https://docs.leaningtech.com/cheerpj/Getting-Started

Full disclosure, I am CTO of Leaning Technologies and lead developer of CheerpJ